# Official C++/11 Makefile Standard/Alternatives?

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, build-automation, portability

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012, Eclipse, CodeBlocks, and MinGW to write C++ 11 code.

**Question:**

I have noticed features in GCC, (deferred, = vs. immediate, :=, expansions/assignments, etc), and Microsoft's nmake that lead me to wonder what the official "makefile" standard was.

1. Was there an update to the makefile standards with C++11?
2. I know where the GNU makefile standard is, (http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), but where can I find "The" makefile standard?
3. To be honest, I would much rather write makefiles in C++, and run them as scripts from a shell; is there a way to run C++ code as scripts?  Perhaps Javascript?  What other Scripting Languages are used to do this?

**Background:**

The difficulty, (*cough), is that I am trying to make sure the code compiles in each environment, as well as trying to cross-compile to other targets as well, (Linux/Ubuntu using OpenGL APIs, Windows 7,8, using DirectX, Android NDK).

One of my core issues is that a lot of the toolsets I am using aren't really "open" to supporting cross platform awesomeness.

Visual Studio 2012: 
No *nix runnable compiler. 
Using buggy version of Nov. 2012 C++ CTP Compiler for C++11 support.

GCC 4.7.x/4.8x:
Limited to MinGW32 and rough versions of MinGW64.

CMake:
Very difficult to get configured correctly, but appears to create makefiles that are specific to GNU, Microsoft, etc.  Is there some way to configure this to generate "standard" makefiles?

AutoMake/AutoConf: 
Appear to only generate GNU compatible makefiles

Comment: makefile and c++ are two independent things

Comment: Make, as well as most build systems, are language independent.  While there are some "best practices" these are more dependent on the build system you're using(CMake, gnu make, etc) than they are on the language you're building for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only standard for makefiles is Posix
(http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html).
This is not followed by Visual Studios, and the MinGW make is
actually GNU make, which has an option to be Posix compatible,
but has a very large number of extensions.  (I'm not sure about
Eclipse and CodeBlocks, but they probably use GNU make as well.)

The makefile you use is largely independent of the compiler.
The Posix standard make is a minimum make; I would recommend
using GNU make everywhere, mainly because it *is* portable, and
it is the most powerful in terms of features.  On the other
hand, it's not easy to learn (and none of the makes I know are
particularly readable).  Still, I've used the same GNU makefiles
under Solaris (with Sun CC and g++), Linux (with g++) and
Windows (with MSVC and g++).

With regards to running C++ from the makefile, I also do this
all the time, as well as running Python and shell scripts.
There are two ways to do this:

- You want to integrate the output of your C++ into the
  makefile itself, GNU make is really your only solution (I
  think), using `$(shell ... )`  (Where I worked until recently,
  the "reference" was the VS project files; we used `$(shell ...)`
  to invoke a Python script which parsed the project files to
  generate the list of target files and dependencies in the
  makefile.)
- If you want to invoke a C++ program to generate sources for
  later compilation, you can create dependencies for the source
  file:

  ```
      machineGenerated.cpp : somethingElse myPreProcessor
              myPreProcessor somethingElse > machineGenerated.cpp
  ```

  You can also have rules to build `myPreProcessor` in the
  makefile.

One thing I've found useful when supporting multiple platforms:

```
dependsPath       := $(strip $(arch))-$(strip $(syst))-$(strip $(comp))
configPath        := conf/$(dependsPath)
include $(makefilesDir)/$(configPath)/system.mk
```

Normally, I'll set shell variables for my default arch, syst and
comp (compiler), but I can override them on the command line,
and so compile with both g++ and VC++ on the same machine (or
`i686` and `x86-64`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The POSIX reminder made it all come back together for me.  I really appreciate your help.  Now that I am thinking in terms of Posix, I think it will be better for me to just drop makefiles altogether and look for something a bit more platform neutral.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

There is no C++ Standard for make systems.  This is purely implementation defined stuff.

For cross-platform work (being both cross-operating system and cross-toolchain), I have found the most popular choice being [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).  I'm not a fan of CMake's syntax or various complexities, and I don't enjoy working with it -- but it does work, and it seems like everybody uses it.  CMake skills you gain working on one project will transfer to many others.

Yes, you can get "standard" makefiles out of CMake.  This is a function of the generator:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ...
```

Will generate makefiles compatible with *nix `make`.

Comment: Thanks!  That answers all of the standards questions. :)  Are there any alternatives to the makefile syntax?  I mean, are there javascript scripting libraries that have the ability to manuipulate folders, files, and execute commands?  Or perhaps a way of running C++ as a script on various platforms?

Comment: C++ isn't a scripting language, so there's no way to directly run C++ as a script.  However, there are many scripting languages in the world, such as Ruby, Perl and Python, and perhaps one of those will meet your needs.  All the languages I've mentioned, by the way, are free, open-source, and included in standard Linux distros.  they are to varying degrees easy to use and powerful.

Comment: @WindAndFlame if you want something to build code across platforms, implemented in an imperative programming language, you could look at [scons](http://www.scons.org/), which uses python. I have found it less painful than CMake, although it is not as widely used (in fact, I never use it for real for that reason).

Comment: I've no experience with `cmake`, but I've used GNU make on all of the usual platforms.  There's a port to Windows, and it uses autoconf so it compiles on all (or at least almost all) Unix.  If you use it, you don't need any additional tool to create the makefiles/project files.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks!  SCons is definitely an alternative that I will look into.  It is based on Python, which is cross platform, so it may work for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GNU make is an implementation of the POSIX specification for make, which you can find here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/  Under "Shell and Utilities", search for "make".  However you will quickly discover that the parts of make which are standardized are very anemic and won't let you create very sophisticated make environments.  That's why GNU make has so many additional features and capabilities.

Additionally, Windows developers don't care that much about POSIX, and especially not the shell & utilities section of POSIX.  So even if you can restrict yourself to that subset it doesn't buy you that much: portability across instances of POSIX which don't already use GNU make, basically (both Linux and MacOS use GNU make by default).

You basically have two choices: you can either get a build tool that will work across multiple platforms (GNU make, for example, can be compiled and used on just about every OS available today, but there are other tools such as scons, cook, bras, etc.), or you can use a "meta-tool" like cmake, which instead of actually building your code it will generate build control files for whatever native build tool you want to use (make, Eclipse, XCode, VisualStudio) then you use that native build tool.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: ***There is no multi-platform Makefile Standard: Instead, use standard, multi-platform scripting languages, such as PHP, PERL, Python, (SCons), etc, to Compile C++ Projects***

Based on everyone else's comments about their not being a unified standard, the need for a more permanent, extensible, cross-platform-aly elegant solution became a lot more important to me, (besides, I loathe making makefiles!).

So, after looking at Perl, JavaScript, PHP, (even Python script), I settled on using PHP to Build C++ Projects.

There are so many reasons I made this particular choice, but the main reasons were: 
1. Number of PHP tools
2. Easy integration this into remote build operations via web interfaces.
3. Windows, Linux, BSD, OSX portability.
4. Support for advanced logic, includes, for projects involving many nested folder structures, namespaces, and cross-compilation.

PHP, with its shell scripting support, cross platform availability, etc, is a natural fit.

So, without further ado, here is a small, quick and dirty Proof of Concept I have just made.  Obviously it doesn't "do" anything, but it runs/compiles just fine, and how it would work in a real make file is easily seen.

Thanks for all the help!

```
<?php

// Windows cannot "del /files/*.o /S /Q" because it confuses paths for switches.
// Made my own Variable for Directory Separator for Readability.
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;


// ***********************************************
// **** Compiler Variables
// ***** use PHP: include "Config.php", etc
// ***** to have external variables and functions.

$Compiler   = "mingw32-g++.exe";
$DebugFlags     = ""; 

$CompilationFlags   = "-std=c++11 -Wall -c -o";
$LinkFlags      = "-Wall -o";

$IncludeFlags = 
    array(
        "-I".$DS."Includes", 
        "-L".$DS."Redist".$DS."Headers"
    );
$LibraryLocations =
    array(
        "-L".$DS."Lib",
        "-L".$DS."Redist".$DS."Lib"
    );

// ***********************************************
// **** Project Properties
class Project {
    public $Name = "";
    public $Location = ""; 

    public function __construct($name="Project", $location="")
    {
        $this->Name = $name;
        $this->Location = $location;
    }
}

$SubProjects = 
    array(
        new Project("Framework", str_replace("/", $DS, "../Projects/API/Source")) 
        // new Project("Logging", str_replace("/", $DS, "../Projects/Logging/Projects/API/Source"),         
    );

// ***********************************************
// **** Environment Variables
$BuildRoot  = "D:".$DS."Build".$DS;
$ObjectRoot = $BuildRoot + "OBJs".$DS;
$LibRoot    = $BuildRoot + "LIBs".$DS;
$RunRoot    = $BuildRoot + "Run".$DS;
$ConfigRoot = getcwd();



$directory    = ".".$DS;
$filterList = array(".", "..");
$commandOutput = array("");
$returnValue = 1;

$directoryContents = array_diff(scandir($directory), $filterList);


// ***********************************************
// ***** Main Execution Block

// print_r($SubProjects);

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo "***********************************************" . PHP_EOL;
echo "***** Building: Starting" . PHP_EOL;

ProcessSubProjects($SubProjects);
echo "***********************************************" . PHP_EOL;
echo "***** Building: Finished" . PHP_EOL;



// ***********************************************
function ProcessSubProjects($subProjects)
{
    foreach ($subProjects as $project)
    {
        $command = 'dir ' .  realpath($project->Location);
        $commandEcho = array();

        // echo $project->Location . PHP_EOL;
        // echo realpath($project->Location) . PHP_EOL;


        echo PHP_EOL . $command . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

        exec ($command, $commandEcho);
        foreach ($commandEcho as $message)
        {
            echo $message . PHP_EOL;
        }

    }
}



?>
```